# Add method doesn't allow repeating elements - Binary Tree (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I have written a code to insert an element in a binary tree recursively, but this one I implemented doesn't allow me to insert a repeated element. The problem is I don't know what to modify in the code so I can insert the same element. For example, I insert 8 as a child of 2, but also I want to insert 8 as a child of 5, different parents but same child. This is the code I have:

```
public class BT<E> {
private Node<E> root;

private class Node<E>{
    private E data;
    private Node<E> left;
    private Node<E> right;
    
    public Node(E data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public boolean add(E child, E parent){
    Node<E> nc = new Node<>(child);
    if(isEmpty() && parent == null){
        root = nc;
        return true;
    }
    Node<E> np = searchNode(parent);
    Node<E> nce = searchNode(child);
    if(nce == null && np != null){
        if(np.left == null){
            np.left = nc;
            return true;
        }
        else if(np.right == null){
            np.right = nc;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private Node<E> searchNode(E data){
    return searchNode(data, root);
}

private Node<E> searchNode(E data, Node<E> p){
    if(p == null)
        return p;
    /*else if(p.data.equals(data))
        return p;*/
    else{
        Node<E> nl = searchNode(data, p.left);
        if(nl != null) return nl;
        return searchNode(data, p.right);
    }
}
```

`}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 8 is already inserted as a child of 2, and 5 is in the tree too. In these lines:

```
    Node<E> np = searchNode(parent);
    Node<E> nce = searchNode(child);
    if(nce == null && np != null){
```

`np` will be the node of 5, and `nce` will be the node of the first 8. `nce` is not `null` so the `if` statement is never executed.